# Как отменить push в Bitbucket (Mercurial)?

Tags: bitbucket, mercurial

Смёрджил ветку удалённо и удалил ещё одну, а локально не сделал pull. Затем локально выполнил commit, но запушить не получается теперь никуда. Как отменить оба push-a?

[image]
**UPD:** Попытка перейти в красную ветку, чтобы смёрджить её с жёлтой
[image]

Comment: Ну так сделайте локально pull, потом смержите если две головы получится. В любом случае проблема решается по факту после pull, а не откатом пушей.

Comment: @insolor, я сделал pull, но уже после осознания произошедшего. Текущее состояние описано выше

Comment: В чем вы видите проблему? Я в дереве на снимке проблем не вижу.

Comment: @insolor, в дереве всё нормально. Смущают два push'a, которые нельзя совершить. А как их отменить, я не знаю

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку пишет?

Comment: @insolor, `abort: push creates new remote head f5da63ccea1b on branch 'newton-method'!
(merge or see 'hg help push' for details about pushing new heads)`

Comment: У вас сейчас две ветки newton-method (точнее две головы у этой ветки, то что буквально написано в ошибке). Попробуйте перейти в желтую ветку и вмержить в нее последнее изменение из красной, и после этого уже пушить.

Comment: @insolor, даже перейти не даёт

Comment: Есть возможность создать на локальном HEAD новую ветку, принудительно сбросить HEAD назад по истории и сделать pull, чтобы потом влить ту новую ветку в подтянутую с сервера?

Comment: @Arhad, давайте попробуем, если расскажите как?

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov, ну написано же: конфликт слияния, попробуйте `hg resolve`. Пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему в лоб. Удалил локально проект и клонировал его из удалённого репозитория